# In magento2,How to inject helper in collection

Tags: magento2, collection, helper

I have created a custom grid, in this grid collection I have to inject helper .while injecting helper in the collection it throws error like this
Type Error occurred when creating object:

My collection:

```
namespace vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Post;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

    class Collection extends AbstractCollection
    {
        /**
         * Define model & resource model
         */
        const YOUR_TABLE = 'xxx';


        protected $helper;
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \vendor\magento\Helper\Userdata $helper,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
            \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
            \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
        ) {
            $this->_init(
                ' vendor\module\Model\Post', ' vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Post'
            );
            parent::__construct(
                $entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,$resource,$helper
            );
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

        }
        protected function _initSelect()
        {
            parent::_initSelect();

            $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.user_id = 2";
        }
```

Comment: Will you please share the code? I think it would be helpful.

Comment: @Mathanagopal shared the code

Comment: 1. I am not seeing the helper method being injected in the constructor. 
2. If you want to use the helper method, pass it as a parameter to the constructor and pass it onto the parent::__constructor.
3.  Also, helpers are best helpful to be used in the controller or block class in Magento.

Comment: I have updated the code with helper ..still error display

Comment: The interceptor file needs to be re-created. So kindly run di:compile and clean cache. Hope this helps

Comment: I have removed generated folder still display same error

Comment: Any update on the issue?

Comment: thanks for your response @shailesh answer worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\YourHelperClass $helper,  
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,
        $resource
    );
}

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(
        'Vendor\Module\Model\Post', ' vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Post'
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ..it was worked for me thanks alot

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your helper before below line

\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null 
as below

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \NameSpace\Module\Helper\YourHelperClass  
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    $this->_init(
        ' vendor\module\Model\Post', ' vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Post'
    );
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,
        $resource
    );
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

}
```

Comment: still it display  Type Error occurred when creating object

Comment: Try giving the helper method after $resource in the constructor. Refer [here](https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/class_magento_1_1_sales_1_1_model_1_1_resource_model_1_1_report_1_1_collection_1_1_abstract_collection.html#a34eb85f0e9f0752c9ad57930f3228a16) for the order in which the constructor expects the parameters. Hope this works.